# How to remove vector of struct that contains vector of int

Tags: c++, vector

**I want to delete some `Val[i]` as follows:**

```
struct Sstruct{
    int v1;
    double v2;
};

struct Sstruct2{
std::vector<int> id;
    double a;
    std::vector<Sstruct > b;
};

std::vector <Sstruct2> Val;
```

I tried this code but I got error, using `std::remove_if`

```
bool TestFun(Sstruct2 id1)
{
    bool result= true;

    if ((id1.a< somevalue) 
     {
        // fails
        result= false;
    }

    return result;
}

void DelFun()
{
    for (int i= 0; i< Val.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!TestFun(Val[i]))
        {
          **// here i don't now how to search for Val[i] that fails in the condition**
          Val.erase(std::remove_if(Val.begin(), Val.end(), 
          Val[i].id.begin()), Val.end());  
        }
    }
}
```

**error:**
C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use for loop loop, just simply use following in `DelFun`

```
Val.erase(std::remove_if(Val.begin(), Val.end(), 
          []( const Sstruct2& id)
         {   // Lambda C++11  use flag -std=c++11
             return  ( id1.a < somevalue ) ;
         }
         Val.end());
```

---

```
// Or without Lambda 

struct TestFun
{
    bool operator()(const Sstruct2& i) const
    {
        return ( id1.a < somevalue ) ;
    }
};

Val.erase(std::remove_if(Val.begin(), Val.end(), 
         TestFun()
         Val.end());
```